# Cutting Substring from a file

Tags: shell

I have the 2 tnsentries of a file with entries like , each entry is in a line.

> AAA_PRD =
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=mmmm01.dimpotiso.org)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)))
>
> BBB_PRD =
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=irkosdap01.nonprod.digrestsiso.org)(PORT=1626))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=BBBDFS)))^

The HOST entry does not always start at the same column length. I want to strip out the entries from the HOST to the end bracket of the host, or better just the HOST entries.

I would like to get the results as

> mmmm01.dimpotiso.org
>
> irkosdap01.nonprod.digrestsiso.org

Thanks

I was partially able to get the information out of my tnsnames.ora file with the below-

```
cat  tnsnamesMaster_March12_2013.ora | grep 'HOST' | cut -f2 -d 'HOST=' | cut -f2 -d'=' | cut -f1 -d ')'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o 'HOST=[^)]*' tnsnamesMaster_March12_2013.ora | cut -c6-
```

`-o` tells grep to print only the matching string, which will be `HOST=` up to but not including the first `)`. Then `cut` that `HOST=` out.

If your `grep` supports perl regexes, you can do it at once by putting the `HOST=` in a lookbehind:

```
grep -oP '(?<=HOST=)[^)]+' tnsnamesMaster_March12_2013.ora
```

---

Apparently `-o` is not POSIX, so the above may not work on them. The following are, as far as I can tell, strictly POSIX compliant and so should work anywhere sane:

```
grep HOST tnsnamesMaster_March12_2013.ora | sed 's/.*HOST=\([^)]*\)).*/\1/'

sed -n '/HOST/s/.*HOST=\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p' tnsnamesMaster_March12_2013.ora
```

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks for replying. I was not able to use the option -o on the grep. I instead used grep -e 'HOST=[^)]*' tnsnamesMaster_March12_2013.ora . The cut seemed to give me other problems with syntax and I was not able to get what i was lookig for. I also tried >grep -ep '(?<=HOST=)[^)]+' tnsnamesMaster_March12_2013.ora, but again I get all the characters even after the closing parenthesis of the HOST. This is AIX and uses bash shell.

Comment: What system are you on that doesn't have `-o`? If you add a space to the `cut` (`-c 6-`), that is posix and so should work on any reasonable system.